# What is the meaning of "G" in G7Turing in "Salvation"?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, salvation

In the book *Salvation*, Peter Hamilton uses the terminology G3Turing, G5Turing, G7Turing to talk about AI. I understand what "Turing" means of course, and the number means the higher the more intelligent.

**What is the meaning of the letter "G"?**

Please don't spoil the book, I have not yet finished reading it.

Comment: Putting this as comment, as I am not certain and do not have the book at hand, but I think it stands for Generation. So G7 would be the seventh AI generation.

Comment: I also immediately thought "Generation". We have the same terminology in mobile communication networks: G2, G3, G4, and the upcoming G5.

Comment: @Erik Generation is a good explanation. I'll take it as an answer if you want to post it.

Comment: HP ProLiant servers were rev'ved by "Generation" and their generation was identified by "G#" - e.g., an HP DL360 G5 would be a 5th generation DL360.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Generation**

The intelligent agents that control computer systems are called Turings. There are references to generations of the technology used throughout the book. The term isn't explicitly defined or explained but is implied in several statements.

> Apart from maintenance crew inspections, people didn't work in the warehouse. It was all automated by **an old G2Turing**.

> *"They would've taken over **the ancient G3Turing drivers** and had themselves the world's greatest demolition battle, smashing those brutes into each other and every other piece of equipment out there."*

> *"No, I'm actually quite impressed. **A Turing above G-five** can do a similar job as you, but it requires access to a thousand databases. But you, you just look. I find that  fascinating."*

> That easier life could have been real **if he'd bought a fifth-generation Turing. They were so much smarter**...

Then there are G6 and up, which are used more often for security, management, and analytical purposes. G7 are sophisticated enough to serve as personal assistants that can read individual's health status and anticipate their needs and next actions.

Comment: Also, there is talk of "genten" on Juloss as being obviously a further evolution - with the naming convention changed from "G10Turing" to just "genten", and explicitely stated to be "generation 10"; further implying the G is indeed for generation